# Python mechanize not using cookies between requests

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm trying to login with mechanize, get the session cookie, then load a protected page but mechanize doesn't seem to be saving or re-using the session. When I try to load the protected resource I get redirected to the login page. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong from the code below?

```
import mechanize
import urllib
import Cookie
import cookielib
cookiejar=cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cookiejar)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 Compatible')]
br.set_cookiejar(cookiejar)

params = {'email_address': 'name@company.com', 'password':pass}
data = urllib.urlencode(params)
request = mechanize.Request('/myLoginPage', data=data)
response = br.open(request)
html = response.read()

request = mechanize.Request('/myProtectedPage')
response = br.open(request)
```

At this point response is not the data from the protected resource its a redirect to the login page

Comment: I think you are missing ``cookiejar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()``?

Comment: that should have been in there, I had it in my code but didn't put it in the example